# Android: custom view data binding: bind values from system attrs.xml

Tags: android, data-binding, android-edittext

I want to pass values like `EditText`'s `imeOption` and `inputType` to a custom view (which contains an `EditText`) using `@BindingAdapter` so it can be customizable from the view that will be using it.

Ideally this would go:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("customEditText:imeOptions")
fun setImeOption(view: CustomEditText, inputVariable: Int) {
    view.binding.editText.imeOptions = inputVariable
}
```

and in xml:

```
<CustomEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    customEditText:imeOptions="@{actionDone}"/>
```

but `actionDone` cannot be resolved. It there any way to do this?

Note: `CustomEditText` does not extend EditText, it's just a `LinearLayout` which contains an `EditText` among other views

Comment: CustomEditText is textview? CustomEditText edit what kind of view?

Comment: @sasikumar edited, it's nothing related to edittext or textView

Comment: then why you want to customEditText:imeOptions="@{actionDone}" ?

Comment: CustomEditText contains an EditText among other views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the data tags, import the EditorInfo class:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo"/>
</data>
```

And set it like:

```
customEditText:imeOptions="@{EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE}"
```